# Making Linux unzip command just extract files from directories whose names contain a given string

Tags: wildcards, zip, pattern-matching

I have a zip archive that contains a directory hierarchy of files. I want to use the Linux unzip command to extract just the subset of these files that have a particular string somewhere in the directory path leading up to the file.

For example, suppose the file foo.zip contains these files:

```
a/1.txt
acme/2.txt
a/acme/b/3.txt
a/b/acmenet/c/4.txt
a/b/c/5.txt
a/acme/d/6.php
```

The Linux command "unzip foo.zip *.txt" will extract all 5 of the "txt" files.

How can this Linux command be modified so that it only extracts the 3 "txt" files that have the string "acme" somewhere in the directory path (so it would extract only 2.txt, 3.txt and 4.txt)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example `unzip foo.zip *.txt` only worked because there was no `*.txt` file in your working directory. Otherwise `*.txt`
would have been expanded by the shell to the names of the text files in your directory. You need to quote it to be on the safe side.

Since `unzip` uses globs, use

```
unzip foo.zip '*acme*/*.txt'
```

or even

```
unzip foo.zip '*acme*.txt'
```

If you don't want to restore the original directory structure and extract the files to the current working directory, add option `-j`:

```
unzip -j foo.zip '*acme*/*.txt'
```